# Redirect httpd file

Tags: regex, apache

I tried editing httpd file using all the solutions i found to redirect a https://pc.web.com/MyWeb/MyWebPortal.portal;jsessionid=jZLxT04pfQ (example website) to http://pc.web.com.

But none of the solutions are working! can anyone could guide me on this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName pcnow.web.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"


RewriteCond %{pc.web.com} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

even redirect is also not working!!

Comment: For starters you might consider editing/creating an `.htaccess` file instead. It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to run Apache in a more appropriate directory too; having spaces in web enabled file paths is not recommended.

Comment: Could you please share one example?(where you have edited .htaccess) i'm struck at this for more than 2days. I want an example where you have done that somewhat similar may be.

Comment: PS: Where to find .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName pcnow.web.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
RewriteCond %{pc.web.com} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
...
```

First, you want to redirect `https` request to `http` so your virtual host should probably listen to port 443 and you should set the certificate and the appropriate SSL configurations in it.

Second, you have a typo in the server name `ServerName pcnow.web.com` should be `ServerName pc.web.com`.

Third, your `RewriteCond` is invalid. 
The RewriteCond syntax should be in the form of:
`RewriteCond TestString CondPattern [flags]`.

So in your case the TestString will be something like: `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

And the CondPattern should be a regex matching what all URIs that need to be redirected, for example: `^/MyWeb/MyWebPortal\.portal;jsessionid=.*`.

Or all together:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/MyWeb/MyWebPortal\.portal;jsessionid=.*`.

And last, the `RewriteRule` second parameter contracting an invalid URL to redirect. The reason is it concatenating the value of the RewriteRule expression match with the value of the RewriteCond condition match which was written incorrectly.

The RewriteRule rule should as follow: `RewriteRule .* http://pc.web.com [R=301,L]`.

you can take a look over here for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html